# function $f:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ is monotone increasing, prove that $\lim_{x→c−} f(x) = \sup\{f(x):x < c\}$

Tags: real-analysis

function $f:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ is monotone increasing, prove that $\lim_{x→c−} f(x) = \sup\{f(x):x < c\}$

How can I prove this problem ??

Comment: Without context, it is difficult for people to give an answer that is useful to you. You could, for instance, add your own work on this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let $M=\sup\{f(x)\colon x<c\}$. Then, for each $\epsilon>0$, we
can find $x_{\epsilon}<c$ such that $f(x_{\epsilon})+\epsilon\geq M$.
Since $f$ is nondecreasing, this implies that $f(x)+\epsilon\geq M$
for all $x\geq x_{\epsilon}$, which in turn implies $|M-f(x)|\leq\epsilon$
for all $x_{\epsilon}\leq x<c$, as desired.